# GCD Serial thread execution flow

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

In the following sample function

```
    -(void)testThred{
    dispatch_queue_t serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.unique.name.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

    dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
        NSLog(@"1");
    });
     NSLog(@"2");

    dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
        NSLog(@"3");
    });
NSLog(@"4");

}
```

the output is as follows 2,1,4,3

as per my knowledge it will be 2, 4 ,1,3 anyone know how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only order that is guaranteed here is that 4 will happen after 2, and 3 will happen after 1. This is because both your custom queue and the main queue are serial – and therefore blocks are executed in the order in which they were scheduled.

However, because your `serialQueue` is executing blocks on a *background* thread (try logging the current thread) – your 1 and 3 operations are happening concurrently with your 2 and 4 operations.

Therefore the exact ordering between the operations on your serial queue and operations on the main queue is undefined.

If you changed your `dispatch_async` to dispatch to the main queue, then you'll indeed get the ordering you want (2, 4, 1, 3) – as the blocks you schedule will have to wait for the main queue to finish executing it's current task (your 2 and 4 operations + whatever else the main queue is doing).